# ASP.NET XML parsing error only on FireFox

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I get this  wired error only when I try to access the web page in FireFox.. IE works just fine..

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/site/Home.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I get this error only on FF 3.5.8 .. 3.6 works just fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the right answer.. but upgraded to FF 3.6 and it works just fine..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be accessing the page from the file system directly. Check the URLs in the address bar.

Comment: I did, it's the same url.. I'm trying to access..  
I get this error only on FF 3.5.8 .. 3.6 works just fine..